# - sign after << in ruby heredoc

Tags: ruby, heredoc

In the followings, both of them outputs the same things. I am not suer the point of having - after <<, like <<-END rather than <

```
class Poem


def initialize
    @text = <<END
"Faith" is a fine invention
When Gentlemen can see
But Microscopes are prudent
           In an Emergency.
(Emily Dickinson 1830-1886)
END
  end
  def recite
    puts @text
  end
end

poem = Poem.new
poem.recite

class Poem1
  def initialize
    @text = <<-END
"Faith" is a fine invention
When Gentlemen can see
But Microscopes are prudent
           In an Emergency.
(Emily Dickinson 1830-1886)
    END
  end
  def recite
    puts @text
  end
end

poem1 = Poem1.new
poem1.recite
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The minus sign `-` after the `<<` characters means you can indent the terminator.

So if the here document starts with `@text = <<END`, you must terminate with `END` in the beginning of the line. But with `@text = <<-END`, you can put space before `END`.

```
    @text = <<-END
"Faith" is a fine invention
When Gentlemen can see
But Microscopes are prudent
           In an Emergency.
(Emily Dickinson 1830-1886)
    END
#^^^ Here white space
```

Comment: Ok, so if I don't add - and indent END, I get an error. Thanks.

Comment: Is this just for historic reasons, or is there some wisdom behind this distinction?

Comment: @BaselShishani As I recall, Perl here document doesn't support this usage, so it doesn't seem like for historic reasons.